# Redirect in php server side after http request

Tags: php, http-redirect

I am very new to php so this question might be trivial.
I am trying to understand if it is possible to redirect the browser from php server side to the page returned by HTTP request.

I have a HTTP Post request looking like so:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
       "someData" => "data" ,
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $postdata,
        'header'  =>
            "Cookie: someCookie" .
            'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
    )

);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = fopen('myWebsiteUrl', 'r', false, $context);

var_dump(stream_get_contents($result));
```

In the post I am being redirected to a different page with Get.
I am trying to force the browser to move to the 'redirected' page. With the above code I am getting back the html of the redirected page but what I'm after is an actual redirect.
The option of retrieving the redirect URL and doing the redirect myself in PHP doesn't work because the Get request has to happen within the same session as the Post.

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Location: whereveryouwantogo.php?get=123456');
```

does a redirect for you with a GET-parameter attached. I'm not sure if I really got your question right, but I'm pretty sure you could do what you want/need with the header-command.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the last sentence, doing the redirect after the http won't work. The redirect is done within the http action.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. I don't think this is possible the way you'd like to have it.

Comment: Thanks. I thought this might be the case.